# Set auto height to label

Tags: html, css

Set auto height to label based on above div. I tried below code please check with fiddle. I set `height:auto` to label. Its not supported to this label. I need to that right side image to equal of left side checkbox height.

```
jsfiddle.net/malaiii/3vej0tca/
```

Comment: Show the code that you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set height of column is equal to height of other column you can use position absolute for column that is less than other.

HTML like

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="control">
            <input type="checkbox" /> Click me
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="checkbox" /> Click me
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="checkbox" /> Click me
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 404px;
    overflow: hidden;

    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
    .wrapper .left {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;

        border: 1px dotted #00f;
    }
    .wrapper .right {
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;

        background: #efefef;
    }
    .wrapper .right img {
        height: 100%;
    }
.control {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

See fiddle with example http://jsfiddle.net/588efqtf/2/

Hope it'll help you.